# Netbeans trunks (pre-7.0): JUnit bundling removed - no plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, junit

Since 2011-02-06 trunk build of **Netbeans** (probably earlier), **JUnit is removed**, [as it was proposed](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Oracle-may-remove-JUnit-from-NetBeans-1171112.html).

Sadly, there seem to be still no plugin for JUnit from *Tools->Plugins->Availible...*, which would act as a drop-in replacement. Perhaps, no post-installable drop-in replacement is even planned.

Sure, I could define a new custom Netbeans library and install JUnit manually *(which is what I might do, when there is no better solution)*.

**But, I asking you guys: does anyone know of a better solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In more recent trunk builds of Netbeans (as of 2011-03-31), installation of JUnit plugin is offered separated during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there doesn't seem to be a better solution. I hope they will solve problems with the licence soon and final version will be with jUnit. There's also the item "Tools > Create JUnit Tests" now missing